# jssor AutoPlay undefined

Tags: jquery, undefined, jssor

I am using an AutoPlay value 14 which correctly stops on last slide or on click and user navigation. I want to visually reflect whether the slide show is paying. Unfortunately, I was expecting the current status. 
Suggestions?

```
jssor_1_slider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE,function(position, fromPosition){
    My_URL_Update(position, fromPosition);
    SlidesCount = jssor_1_slider.$SlidesCount();    //returns correct number
    console.log('SlidesCount: ' +  SlidesCount);
    MyAutoPlay  = jssor_1_slider.$AutoPlay();    //get AutoPlay
    console.log('AutoPlay : ' +  MyAutoPlay ); // returns Undefined

}); // EVT_POSITION_CHANGE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `var` to define the variable.

```
jssor_1_slider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE,function(position, fromPosition){
    My_URL_Update(position, fromPosition);
    var SlidesCount = jssor_1_slider.$SlidesCount();    //returns correct number
    console.log('SlidesCount: ' +  SlidesCount);
    var MyAutoPlay  = jssor_1_slider.$AutoPlay();    //get AutoPlay
    console.log('AutoPlay : ' +  MyAutoPlay ); // returns Undefined

}); // EVT_POSITION_CHANGE
```

**Edit**

It's a bug, it has been fixed.

Comment: Again, thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, I get the same results. Suggestions on where to investigate?

Comment: @Rich Stadtmiller Thanks a lot! It's a bug, we fixed it. And jssor.slider-25.3.1.min.js is available for download on our website.

Comment: Cool. Since I wrote my first JS code about 6 weeks ago, I am never sure when it is cockpit error.

Comment: Just tried it and am now getting the info I expected. I will let it run to the end and pause to verify, but for now it no longer returns undefined. Kudos!

Comment: Update: Apparently, when it stops at the end of the slide, there is no EVT_POSITION_CHANGE with an AutoPlay = 0. Looks like PARK does the job.
THx

Comment: Thanks! I will have look carefully.

Comment: correction - s/end of the slide/end of the slide list/